# Use data retrieved from HTTPClient into JSoup

Tags: java, html, http, jsoup, httpclient

I am using HTTPClient to connect to a website.The following snippet of code is used for this purpose:

```
 byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
 System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
```

The above code displays the html code of website. 
Further I wanted to access only some data from the code which I was able to access using JSoup using following code snippet:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

In the above code I have directly specified url of website using "url". which means I do not require HTTPClient if I use JSoup.
Is there a way I can use  " responseBody" retrieved using HTTPClient to be integrated in JSoup code so that I do not have to use Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse the `HTML` directly through `Jsoup#parse`:

```
Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(new String(responseBody));
```

Though I have my concerns of converting byte array to String directly, in your case however it should work fine.

The other way, I can use `URLConnection` and get a handle on the `InputStream` and parse it to a String with the provided charset encoding:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
        InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        String htmlText = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(inStream, connection.getContentEncoding());

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
        Elements els = document.select("tbody > tr > td");

        for (Element el : els) {
            System.out.println(el.text());
        }
```

Would give:

```
Stack Overflow Server Fault Super User Web Applications Ask Ubuntu Webmasters Game Development TeX - LaTeX
Programmers Unix & Linux Ask Different (Apple) WordPress Answers Geographic Information Systems Electrical Engineering Android Enthusiasts Information Security
Database Administrators Drupal Answers SharePoint User Experience Mathematica more (14)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried
Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(new String(responseBody));
before your answer and it worked. I will definitely try the second way too. Thanks. I have accepted your answer.